# Updating a field value of one object is changing the field value of the source object

Tags: vb.net

I have the following class `Fluid` which I want to have several fields to store data about the fluid. I also have `Fluid_tbl As List(of Fluid)`

```
  Public Class Fluid
        Public Index As Boolean            
        Public MassFlow As Double          
        Public Pres As Double              
        Public Temp As Double              
        Public comp(30) As Double           
        Public str As Double             
        Public Prop(10) As Double
    End Class
```

When I try to do a calculation where I assign properties to one fluid based on another, the original fluid is also being overwritten. I want all of these to pass as values, but the ones specified as arrays are being passed as references?

For example, in the following loop I want to scale each component in stream MA to stream AP based on the relative overall flow, but `Fluid_Tbl(MA).comp(i)` also seems to be getting changed.

```
For i = 0 To 30
     Fluid_tbl(AP).comp(i) = Fluid_Tbl(MA).comp(i) * Fluid_Tbl(AP).MassFlow / Fluid_Tbl(MA).MassFlow
Next i
```

Edit

I guess I wasn't explicit enough. My issue is not that there is only one object. I said my issue was with the properties specified as arrays because the other ones (e.g. MassFlow, Pres, Temp) are being assigned properly with no issue. I think I've narrowed my issue down to this function which I got from another SO thread:

```
    Sub CopyProperties(CopyTo As Object, CopyFrom As Object)

        For Each Prop As System.Reflection.FieldInfo In CopyFrom.GetType().GetFields

            CopyTo.GetType().GetField(Prop.Name).SetValue(CopyTo, Prop.GetValue(CopyFrom))

        Next

    End Sub
```

I wanted this function to copy all of the field values from one `Fluid` to another as just setting them equal apparently instead sets one as a reference to the other instead. But for some reason this sub causes the above `for loop` to pass each `.comp(i)` as a reference (not calling the function results in the behavior I want, where they are passed as values)

Here's a reduced code that shows my issue

```
Private Sub Example()
       
   Fluid_Tbl = New List(Of Fluid)
          For i = 0 To 1
            Dim fld As New Fluid
            Fluid_Tbl.Add(fld)
         Next

        Dim MA, AP As Integer
        MA = 0
        AP = 1

        Fluid_tbl(MA).comp(0) = 100
        Fluid_tbl(MA).comp(1) = 50
        Fluid_tbl(MA).MassFlow = 100

        Fluid_tbl(AP).MassFlow = 200

        
        CopyProperties(Fluid_tbl(AP), Fluid_tbl(MA))
        Fluid_tbl(AP).MassFlow = 0

        If Fluid_tbl(MA).MassFlow > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To 30
                Fluid_tbl(AP).comp(i) = Fluid_tbl(MA).comp(i) * Fluid_tbl(AP).MassFlow / Fluid_tbl(MA).MassFlow
            Next i
        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Fluid_tbl`?  The behavior described suggests that you only have one `Fluid` object and are trying to modify multiple references to that same object.  But the code shown doesn't create *any* `Fluid` objects.  Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You need to learn how reference types (classes) work. There is almost certainly just one object. You need to show us the code that comes before, because the issue is almost certainly how you're creating the object(s) and populating the collection.

Comment: Consider this. You have a friend and you both go to school. In programming terms, you are both instances of the `Student` class. You are already in a class so you already have a teacher, i.e. your `Teacher` property is set to an object. Your friend joins the same class and so they now also have a teacher, i.e. their `Teacher` property is set too. If you gave your teacher a white hat and they put it on, then you asked your friend if their teacher was wearing a white hat, would you be surprised that they said "yes"? Of course not, because there's only one `Teacher` object, not magically two.

Comment: @David I defined what Fluid_tbl was in my post but I've more clearly laid out everything for you

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm aware of reference types, which is why I'm asking why something is acting as a reference when I'm expecting it to work as a value.  If I have a faulty understanding of class fields/properties/etc that is what I'm hoping to fix by coming here. Please see my update for what I think is the perpetrator

Comment: Your `Fluid` class should implement the [ICloneable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=net-8.0) Interface. In the `Clone` method implementation, do deep or shallow copy (understand the [difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-8.0)) as you need and return it. Then modify the values of the new object. Nothing changes in the cloned object.

Comment: @Tarluna: So `Fluid_Tbl` is a `List(Of Stream)`?  Then what uses the class `Fluid`?  The updated example uses some property called `m` instead of `comp`.  You seem pretty confused on what actual code you're asking about.  Though that `CopyProperties` is certainly suspect.  If you copy an array reference from one object's property to another then both objects will be using the same array reference.  So changes to one reference to that array will be visible from any other reference to that array.  It sounds like this method is the problem.

Comment: @david ah my apologies. I pulled the code example from a previous copy I was using test as I changed old vb6 code. `Stream` should have been updated to `Fluid` as it seemed that was an existing class, and `.m` should have been updated to the slightly more appropriate `.comp`. Is there a simple way to pass array values or does it suffer from the same issue as the class where I will need to iterate through it?

Comment: @dr.null thank you for your suggestion. Clone seems to create a new object, so in this case is there an easy method to delete the existing one and replace it with the clone in my `List`?

Comment: Don't add two objects in `Fluid_Tbl`. Get rid of the `For` loop. Create the base/first object and add it to the list, clone the object, modify its properties, and lastly, add it to the list. That's it all.

Comment: @dr.null Unfortunately then this is not a solution for me as the nature of the program is to do iterative calculations.

Comment: @Tarluna: You can deep-copy objects, arrays, etc. all you like.  Making a general purpose function which can do that for any possible object could be difficult.  But for any given class you can implement its own custom functionality to create a copy/clone of itself.  The ICloneable interface is a standard interface for this expected functionality.